# no definition of 'Bootstrap' TwitterBootstrapMVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this library TwitterBootstrapMVC but does not recognize me

```
@Html.Bootstrap().ActionLinkButton("Link Text", "action")
```

Why should it be?

Comment: Have you installed Bootstrap? Do you have a using statement? using TwitterBootstrapMVC; Any console errors?

Comment: if I have everything installed from the package nuget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should follow the instruction on TwitterBootstrapMVC website, especially if you are using Bootstrap 3:

https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/Home/Installation